# Django anonymous user in model

Tags: django, model, anonymous

I have a model defined as below:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    other = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The problem is Django refuses to assign django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser directly to Example.user as null field so everytime I have to check if request.user.is_authenticated() ans assign Example.user = None manually.

Is there a default value for AnonymousUser to use in a model field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only users actually in `django.contrib.auth.models.User` can be in the field, so no. Stick with `None`/`NULL`.